# How do I make an image its actual size up to a certain point in a window? Extjs 6 classic

Tags: image, extjs, window

I want to have a `window` xtype that contains just an of its own size but when I show my window, it shows up as a tiny square in the middle of the screen (not the actual size of the image). I've tried using this block of code

```
listeners:{
            afterrender: function(me){
                me.el.on({
                    load: function (evt, ele, eOpts){
                        me.updateLayout();
                    },
                    error: function(evt,ele,eOpts){
                    }
                });
            }
        }
```

to update the layout of the parent window from within the `image` xtype, but this makes the window not centered and centering the window during an `afterrender` event isn't working. Am I missing something simple? I also have the `maxWidth` and `maxHeight` configs of the `image` set to `Ext.getBody().getViewSize().width` and `height` respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Sencha had a good reason not to use `xtype: 'image'` for their own icons etc.

`xtype: 'image'` only works with fixed width and height, so you can't even preserve aspect ratio, as far as I know.

What you want to do is to have a container and set the background-image of the container.

```
xtype: 'container',
style: 'background-image: url(\'image.jpg\'); background-repeat:no-repeat; background-position:50% 50%; background-size:contain'
```

or even just use the window: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/244n